# Get all user profiles in a SharePoint 2019 list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

Browser throws an error after changing the web.config file:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
    <fieldset>
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x800700b7
Config Error       Config section 'appSettings' already defined. Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic <location> for exceptions
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\22463\web.config
Requested URL      http://sp-front:22463/personal/site-name
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
Config Source:
 1414:   </microsoft.identityModel>
 1415: <appSettings>
 1416:     <add key="syncUserName" value="CO\sp-admin" />
    </fieldset>
```

I follow the example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029168/How-to-Synchronize-Active-Directory-Users-to-a-Sha
What could be the problem?

Comment: The link is from 2015 and may not work with the latest CORE library.  The CORE library has significantly changes from 2015.

Comment: And there is a new solution how to send a list of users from AD to the SahrePoint 2019 list?

Comment: The URL is HTTP not HTTPS.  The authentication (login method) method probably changed.  Most systems are moving to OAUTH2.  The web.config file may not exist.  The version of Core has changed (IIS Web Core).  IIS may not work because of TLS issues.